# A/C generator = RPC?

Tags: three-phase

I need 3ph power to run metalworking machines in my home shop.  I've landed on utilizing a rotary phase converter to accomplish this.  Some time ago, I took a 10kw 3ph generator on trade for some work.  Can the engine be removed from this unit and wired to run as an RPC in the way motors are used in this fashion?

Edit:. A traditional RPC is a 3ph motor with power supplied to t1 & t2 which turn the idler motor that, then, generates 3 legs of power that are  regulated via capacitors between t1/t3 & t2/t3

Comment: You want to replace the engine with an electric motor?

Comment: Sounds very doable.more practical details would help. If you can run the alternator at a steady and suitable speed it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Electrically, there should be no reason that you can not convert an engine-generator set to a motor generator set. However, unless you can obtain a synchronous motor, the output frequency will be about three percent less than your utility power frequency.

You will need to determine if the generator is 2-pole, 3600/3000 RPM at 60/50 Hz or 4-pole, 1800/1500 RPM at 60/50 Hz. Then you will need to get a matching single-phase motor. A single-phase induction motor of the same power rating may be quite difficult to find. A single-phase synchronous motor will likely be impossible to find.

You might consider variable frequency drives (VFDs) for each machine. In power ratings in below 1 or 2 kW, there are a variety of VFDs available that accept single-phase input power and provide three-phase output power.

Comment: I'd second the VFD idea.  Many VFD's today include minor PLC functionality; it is feasible to sample the output frequency and feed that in as a voltage or current, in order to create an electronic governor of sorts (if maintaining output frequency is a major concern.)